# angualrjs - factory not properly injecting, getting error

Tags: angularjs, angular-factory

I have created the separate file for my `modules`, after i am creating a `factory` service. later I am trying to use in my controller,  but i am getting an error as :

`Unknown provider: authFactoryProvider <- authFactory <- mainController`

what is wrong here?

my module file :

```
(function(){

    "use strict";

    var ngModules =  ['ui.router'];

    var appModules = ['meanOffice.factories','meanOffice.controllers', 'meanOffice.directives'];

    var modules = [];

    modules = modules.concat( ngModules );
    modules = modules.concat( appModules );

    angular.module('meanOffice.factories',[]);
    angular.module('meanOffice.controllers', []);
    angular.module('meanOffice.directives', []);

    angular.module( 'meanOffice', modules );

})();
```

my factory:

```
(function(){

    "use strict";
     // alert('hi'); -works 

    angular.module('meanOffice.factories')
        .factory('authFactory', function($scope){

            var authFactory = {};


            authFactory.init = function(){

                console.log(' init called ');

            }

            return authFactory;

        })

})();
```

Comment: did you add the factory file in index.html

Comment: yes, it was added. in case if I give some alert, it works fine ( out side of factory )

Comment: paste your controller

Comment: You cannot inject $scope into factory. I'm not sure it causes the issue you described but $scope definitely shouldn't be there.

Comment: @janusz - yes you are correct. as a silly mistake it take long time to fix. thanks